ErrorBoundary not catching the error I throw from API call
I have an app that using open api yaml + axios. I create an customInstance for API call, the function is :
export const customInstance = async <T>(
  config: AxiosRequestConfig
): Promise<T> => {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
  const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
  const promise = AXIOS_INSTANCE({
    ...config,
    cancelToken: source.token,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token || ''}`,
    },
  })
    .then(({ data }) => data)
    .catch(async (e: AxiosError) => {
      if (e?.response?.status === 401) {
        // token expired
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('token');
        throw Error('ERR-401');
      }
      throw {
        message: e.message,
        status: e?.response?.status,
        data: e?.response?.data,
      };
    });
  // @ts-ignore
  promise.cancel = () => {
    source.cancel('Query was cancelled by SWR');
  };
  return promise;
};

You can see I try to return a customized error message for redirect user to login page when token is expired, and I add my error boundary into rootLayout, the error boundary is from expo router, the custom error boundary is :
export function ErrorBoundary({ error, retry }: ErrorBoundaryProps) {
  if (error.message === 'ERR-401') {
    // Unauthorized
    return <Redirect href="/" />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{error.message}</Text>
        <Text onPress={retry}>Try Again?</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
}

This has been working previously when I set it up, but after a few iterations, the routing changed. I found out the error now is not caught by the error boundary, instead, there will be a console.log warning showing up at the bottom

Possible unhandled promise rejection(id:0) Error:ERR-401

I tried to use another error boundary lib, but I have the same result, so I am thinking that maybe this throw Error('ERR-401') somehow is not recognized as an error and the boundary is not catching it?
Because when I try to throw an error in the component, the ErrorBoundary is still working.
Is there any possible that this error has been catching by the dev log before the error boundary? If so, how can I solve this?
Thanks!
